# Why MSBuild task does not build a project dependencies?

Tags: visual-studio-2013, msbuild, msbuild-task

I have Visual Studio 2013 solution that has a lot of C# projects.
There is a requirement says that project B must be built after a project (A) build finish.

Project A has no dependency on project B. Project B has dependency on projects A, C and others. All dependencies are defined as project references.

I added a following target to project A:

```
<Target Name="MyAfterBuildStep" AfterTargets="AfterBuild">
  <MSBuild Projects="$(Bproject)" Properties="Configuration=$(ConfigurationName);Platform=$(PlatformName);SolutionDir=$(SolutionDir);BuildProjectReferences=true"/>
</Target>
```

It starts but it does not build dependencies of $(Bproject).

Could someone help me to understand why dependencies are not built and what should I do to build them?

Comment: Do the dependencies defined as project references or file references? is Bproject a solution or a single project?

Comment: As project references. Bproject and other projects mentioned here are  projects in the same solution.

Comment: The requirement is somewhat cumbersome. if project B has dependency on project A, why does project A need to build project B and not the other way around which is the default behavior? your'e forcing circular dependencies and then ask how to avoid them. maybe better explain you're goal so other solutions may be suggested..

Comment: You are right. The goal is simple. The solution has "production" projects and unit test projects for them. Let's call project A is production code and project B is unit tests for classes in project A. Project A has no reference to B, but B has reference to A. Everytime project A build finish (BTW it prevents circular dependencies) project B must be buit also (after that UT will be run).That's all.

Answer (score 1):

If both projects on the same solution, build Bproject as a target with `$(SolutionPath)`, e.g.:

```
<MSBuild Projects="$(SolutionPath)" Targets="Tests\Bproject" Properties="Configuration=$(ConfigurationName);Platform=$(PlatformName);SolutionDir=$(SolutionDir);BuildProjectReferences=true"/>
```

The target name should reflect the name of the project including the solution folders.

Comment: Thank you very much! I can't check it now but it looks nice. I marked this answer as useful but I don't have acceptable reputation.